# Convert list to data frame while keeping list-element names

Tags: r, list, dataframe, r-faq

I have list where the elementnames are ID-tags and contains a vector with numeric values. These are of unequal(!) length.

I want to transform it to a data frame where I have the ID in one column and the numeric values in another column.  E.g.:

```
$`1`  
[1] 1 2   
$`2`  
[1] 1 2 3 
$`3`  
[1] 1
```

To:

```
ID   Obs  
1    1  
1    2
2    1
2    2
2    3
3    1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
## your list
ll <- list("1" = 1:2, "2" = 1:3, "3" = 1:2)
## convert to data.frame
dl <- data.frame(ID = rep(names(ll), sapply(ll, length)),
                 Obs = unlist(ll))
```

This gives:

```
> dl
   ID Obs
11  1   1
12  1   2
21  2   1
22  2   2
23  2   3
31  3   1
32  3   2
```

The first line in the `data.frame()` call is just some code to repeat the `names()` of the list the required number of times. The second line just unlists the list converting it into a vector.

Comment: I gave you the correct answer as your method was fastest: <br/>   >  system.time(melt(X))<br/>
   user  system elapsed <br/>
   3.12    0.11    3.24 <br/>
> system.time(data.frame(ID = rep(names(X), sapply(X, length)),
                  Obs = unlist(X)))<br/>
   user  system elapsed <br/>
   0.08    0.00    0.07<br/>

Comment: I cant seem to add line breaks, sorry for the mess :S

Comment: You can use `lengths` to avoid the `rep(sapply())`.

Comment: @sebastian-c good point, I don't think `lengths()` was part of the language back in 2012, but that would be better now.

Answer (score 10):

Use `reshape2` and `melt` which has a method `melt.list`

```
.list <- list(`1` = 1:2, `2` = 1:3, `3` = 1:2)
library(reshape2)
melt(.list)
##   value L1
## 1     1  1
## 2     2  1
## 3     1  2
## 4     2  2
## 5     3  2
## 6     1  3
## 7     2  3
```

Answer (score 7):

A good and still missing alternative to the already posted solutions is the `stack`-function:

```
df <- stack(ll)[2:1]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>   ind values
> 1   1      1
> 2   1      2
> 3   2      1
> 4   2      2
> 5   2      3
> 6   3      1
> 7   3      2
> ```

---

Using `setNames` as well, you can get the exact desired format:

```
df <- setNames(stack(ll)[2:1], c('ID','Obs'))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>   ID Obs
> 1  1   1
> 2  1   2
> 3  2   1
> 4  2   2
> 5  2   3
> 6  3   1
> 7  3   2
> ```

---

Used data:

```
ll <- list("1" = 1:2, "2" = 1:3, "3" = 1:2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using base functions

```
List <- list('1'=c(1,2), '2'= c(1,2,3), '3'=1)
x <- unlist(List)  # as suggested by Gavin Simpson
data.frame(ID=substr(names(x),1,1), Obs=x)
   ID Obs
11  1   1
12  1   2
21  2   1
22  2   2
23  2   3
3   3   1
```

If you want the `rownames` to be 1,2,3,4,5,6 the try this (using `setNames`):

```
data.frame(ID=substr(names(x),1,1), Obs=setNames(x, NULL))
  ID Obs
1  1   1
2  1   2
3  2   1
4  2   2
5  2   3
6  3   1
```

This solution is valid only if all names have the same length, otherwise it'll fail, and it'd be better using Gavin's solution. See for example:

```
List2 <- list('week1'=c(1,2), 'week2'= c(1,2,3), 'week3'=1)
x <- unlist(List2)  
data.frame(ID=substr(names(x),1,nchar(names(x)[1])-1), Obs=setNames(x, NULL))

    ID   Obs
1 week1   1
2 week1   2
3 week2   1
4 week2   2
5 week2   3
6 week3   1
```

Comment: I think you can just do `x <- unlist(List)` can't you?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson you're right, now I've just edited my answer including your comment.

Comment: It seems like when I unlist it adds a number to the element name causing the rest of the script to fail  for my purpose :S

Comment: @Jilber sorry, but now it changes all the names to either "2" or "5". The elementnames are factors consisting of ID.Seasons.Week, e.g. 2225.Winter.1, if that is of any help. I like the angle of using basic functions when possible so it would be nice if this could work as well..